# Tag synonyms draft list

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We don't seem to be able to use synonyms yet, but I thought I'd put this up as I've already thought of a few, and knowing me, I will forget.

If you have a load, create your own answer, but feel free to use the community wiki one as well.

Comment: You can't actually **add** synonyms. If two tags are created and used that are similar then they can be made into synonyms.

Comment: You now have four users who can create synonyms, but the voting/creation requirements on per-tag score make it harder. Once you get pro-tem mods, ask them to do a synonym/merge.

Answer (score 0):

- os - operating systems
- Console -> CLI
- startup -> boot
- RCA -> Composite video